# Storing data from from 2 separate LocalStorage locations to another single LocalStorage location

Tags: vbscript, nsbasic

This is an [App Studio NSB](https://www.nsbasic.com/) app. Can I store `LocalStorage` data from 2 separate `LocalStorage` locations to another independent `LocalStorage` Location.

The problem I am having is getting the iterations on the `for` loops correct. Or is what I am doing just not possible. (I am an amateur hobby coder)

```
Dim saves, u
Dim saves, i

saves=JSON.parse(localStorage.BrgDst)

For i=0 To UBound(saves)
If  saves[i].Count Then 
Numb = (saves[i].Count)
RFa =(saves[i].RiseFall)
currentRecord=i  

For u = UBound(saves) To 0 Step -1
If  saves[u].Counts Then
RFb =(saves[u].RiseFallX)
currentRecord=u

Dim saves(), datix

datix={PNB: Numb, MRa: RFa, MRb: RFb}

saves=JSON.parse(localStorage.BrgDst)
saves.push(datix)
localStorage.BrgDst=JSON.stringify(saves)

End If
    Next u 
        End If
           Next i
```

This is what I want

> 1)    RiseFall  = -3.822   RiseFallX = 3.821
>
> 2)    RiseFall  = -0.617   RiseFallX = 0.617
>
> 3)    RiseFall  = 0.363   RiseFallX = -0.364

But this is what I get

> 1)    RiseFall  = -3.822   RiseFallX = 3.821
>
> 1)    RiseFall  = -3.822   RiseFallX = 0.617
>
> 1)    RiseFall  = -3.822   RiseFallX = -0.364
>
> 2)    RiseFall  = -0.617   RiseFallX = 3.821
>
> 2)    RiseFall  = -0.617   RiseFallX = 0.617
>
> 2)    RiseFall  = -0.617   RiseFallX = -0.364
>
> 3)    RiseFall  = 0.363   RiseFallX = 3.821
>
> 3)    RiseFall  = 0.363   RiseFallX = 0.617
>
> 3)    RiseFall  = 0.363   RiseFallX = -0.364

Answer (score 0):

First, a better place for this would be the AppStudio discussion board:
https://discuss.appstudio.dev/

I notice in one place you use `saves[i].Count`. Later, you use `saves[u].Counts`. There are no Count or Counts properties in AppStudio BASIC. Could you mean `saved[i].length`?

Comment: Here's the link to the AppStudio discussion which Will opened: https://discuss.appstudio.dev/t/can-i-store-localstorage-data-from-2-separate-localstorage-locations-to-another-independent-localstorage-location/1840